# Error while reading Edit Text content on Button click and displaying in a TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I am implementing a fragment in a navigation drawer menu. I want to read the content of the edit text on clicking a button and display the read content in a text view. But, I am getting the following error:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View**

**Fragment class:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_editText);
    button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_button);
    textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Name = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(Name);
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

}
```

**Fragment xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#566D7E"
tools:context="com.example.jr.mybluetoothchat.ChatFragment">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Enter Text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_editText" />

<Button
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_button" />

<TextView
    android:text="Entered Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/id_editText"
    android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_textView" />
```

**Content Main xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/id_content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BCC6CC"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jr.mybluetoothchat.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chat)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Chat",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ChatFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_content_main,chatFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_invite)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Invite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
editText = (EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_editText);

(In onCreateView) Try This

Comment: `getView()`  always returns null inside onCreateView because it's that method that sets the view. There's nothing to get yet

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thank you!

Comment: @Demo Mail : Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your this code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_editText);
    button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_button);
    textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Name = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(Name);
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

}
```

to this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.id_editText);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.id_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Name = editText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(Name);
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

Comment: @Meghna glad to know that.